# I can't send values of textbox by JSON

Tags: javascript

I'm trying send value by JSON. I enter value on HTML page but it doesn't work. It says "Name is null!";

```html
<form action="" method="post">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Name" class="control-label" id="movieName" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
   
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="file" id="files" name="files" multiple />
    </div>
</form>
```

```js
<script>

        $("#files").fileinput({
        language: 'tr',
        uploadAsync: true,
        dropZoneTitle: "Please drop here pictures",
        browseLabel: "Please choose picture",
        uploadLabel: "Upload",
        uploadUrl: "@Url.Action("Add","Movie")",
        allowedFileExtensions: ['jpg', 'png', 'gif'],
        maxFileCount: 4,
        resizeImage: true,
        maxImageWidth: 800,
        maxImageHeight: 600,
        resizePreference: 'width',
        resizeImageQuality: 0.75,
        uploadExtraData: { name: $("#movieName").val()}
          });
</script>
```

If I enter standart value it works. Like this:

```html
<div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Name" class="control-label" id="movieName" value="Test" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
```

but I want to send on HTML page I entered value. How can i do?

Comment: Seems you didn't attach all of your script?

Comment: I added. İt needs to special .js file.

Comment: Ah, I think the issue is that your script runs on page load directly, before the user has a chance to write something into the input field. That would explain why it works if you hardcode the value in the HTML. What you want is to connect the script to the submit event of your form, so that it is executed when the user submits the form.

Comment: yeah thats ture thanks. But they must be synchronous.when I entered name at the sametime I must upload pics. How can i do?

Answer (score 0):

Your script is being executed as soon as the page loads, even before you have the chance to input something in the form fields. To solve this you need to only run your script when the form is submitted, like this:

```html
<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="submitForm()">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Name" class="control-label" id="movieName" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
   
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="file" id="files" name="files" multiple />
    </div>

    <input type="submit">Submit</input>
</form>
```

```js
<script>
    function submitForm() {
        $("#files").fileinput({
            language: 'tr',
            uploadAsync: true,
            dropZoneTitle: "Please drop here pictures",
            browseLabel: "Please choose picture",
            uploadLabel: "Upload",
            uploadUrl: "@Url.Action("Add","Movie")",
            allowedFileExtensions: ['jpg', 'png', 'gif'],
            maxFileCount: 4,
            resizeImage: true,
            maxImageWidth: 800,
            maxImageHeight: 600,
            resizePreference: 'width',
            resizeImageQuality: 0.75,
            uploadExtraData: { name: $("#movieName").val() }
        });
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

A slightly more clear way would be to use `addEventListener`, like this:

```
<script>
    function submitForm(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // Stop from reloading page etc.
        // Rest of old script code
    }

    document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', submitForm);
</script>
```

This lets you remove the `onsubmit` attribute in the HTML.

Comment: thank you but  this time I can't upload pic.same time. I enter name and click submit, then running scripts but immediately redirects to another page.   this time they are not synchronous and I can upload pics.

Comment: At the end of the submitFrom function add `return false`, this prevents the default action of the form (which is to go to the URL specified by the action attribute, if action is empty it reloads the current page).